# Mix content warning on ASPX page

Tags: internet-explorer

We have started receiving the mixed content warning on ASPX pages on our secured site. We do not have any mix content, we load all our JS, Images, CSS and ASPX files using HTTPS. I dont know why we have started receiving these warnings now.

The latest thing which we have added is the third party control for Dialog boxes from Essential Object. We are previously using their Menu control but added dialog box recently. Also we have made our application browser compatible. I feel the reason is something between these two points. Can anyone suggest any solution or any workaround if they know any or have used Essential Object controls and faced simililar issue? Essential object is saying it is not their problem. The mix content warning appears any time and not specifically when the Essential Control dialog box popsup, thats why I am bit confused. Any help is highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it posted on the internet where we could look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the culprit by viewing the source and looking for occurrences of `http://`. Once thing to check might be tracking code like google analytics if you have any installed. Until recent versions of GA, you had to use different code for http vs. https sites.

Good luck,

--jed

Comment: We checked the application through Fiddler by recording the script but we didnt find any http request (we tried the scenario where mixed content warning is popping up). None of our resource is using http. This warning appears when some progress is going on in backend and we press button or radio button or try to navigate through pages too quickly.